# thrift ssl python server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, thrift

I want to secure the thrift server(just encrypt, and will use acl to do the simeple authentication), and found this: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-secure-and-apache-thrift , but the code is in Java, My thrift server is in Python. I have searched a lot on Google, but found little on this.

I have run the [go version](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/38b1a04b60f1122d94b8e83243f67a9c93182456/tutorial/go/src/server.go#L34) successfully:

```
var transport thrift.TServerTransport
var err error
cfg := new(tls.Config)
if cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("server.crt", "server.key"); err == nil {
    cfg.Certificates = append(cfg.Certificates, cert)
} else {
    return err
}
transport, err = thrift.NewTSSLServerSocket(addr, cfg)
```

while no luck in [Python](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/1568aef7d499153469131449ec682998598f0d3c/test/py/TestServer.py#L216) :

```
from thrift.transport import TSSLSocket
transport = TSSLSocket.TSSLServerSocket(host, port, certfile="server.pem")
```

I have no idea of **server.pem**, is it related with server.key and server.crt？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are all located under [`/test/keys`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/test/keys).

The reason is that they are supposed to be used by multiple (all) languages, so they have been moved into a dedicated folder. Since it is essentially test data, it is `/test/keys`.

Comment: Thanks, so server.crt and server.key are concatenated into server.pem.